# Parse string to date seems to be wrong

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
try {
    String timeString=new String("19860821130102");
    Log.v(TAG, "timeString=" + timeString);
    java.util.Date date = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(timeString);
    Log.v(TAG, date.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use the Snippet above to parse a string to date.
The logcat result is

> timeString=19860821130102
>
> Thu Aug 21 14:01:02 GMT+08:00 1986

I think the hour field should be 13, not 14.
This make me confused.
Any help?

Comment: For readability you should take your string as yyyy-mm-dd-HH-mm-ss as your input string then remove the '-' character this makes it easier to read.. as it is.. I dont want tto even look at your non-filtered string, TLDR especially with no formatting. Make it easier for us to read your code and maybe we'll actually read it :P

Comment: is GMT+8:00 your actual default time zone?

Comment: Maybe the problem is because your GMT

Comment: I run your code, Date hour display 13 .

Comment: your local (the one on your phone) timezone is GMT+07:00 right ?

Comment: You are not printing the day. Then how come THU is coming.also use your locale.don't use the default locale.

Comment: @Ritaban he uses + .toString() which is equivalent to sdf("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy") see the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
SimpleDateFormat Parsed_DATE_TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
try {
    String timeString=new String("19860821130102");
    Log.v(TAG, "timeString=" + timeString);

    TimeZone destTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Log.v=(TAG, "Source TimeZone: " + destTimeZone);

    DATE_TIME_FORMAT.setTimeZone(destTimeZone);
    String convertedDateString = DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(timeString));
    Log.v(TAG, "ConvertedDateString: " + convertedDateString);

    java.util.Date date = Parsed_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.parse(convertedDateString, new ParsePosition(0));
    Log.v(TAG, "ConvertedTime: " + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When I see the word "TimeZone", I realize how stupid my question is.

Comment: @user965244: No question is stupid. I'm glad to know that my answer helped you solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution

```
 String dateString = "03/26/2012 11:49:00 AM";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Comment: I can not see any difference between this code and the one presented in the question, you just add the "aa" string in the pattern. I believe this is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

insert this after the first line

```
DATE_TIME_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0800"));
```

you might want to modify it depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Because `hh` in hours grabs hours from **1 to 12** you can see the encoding [Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Try out as below:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String datenow="19860821130102";
Date date2 = (Date) formatter.parse(datenow);
```